# Selectively load images in PhantomJS (Python+PhantomJS+Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-analytics, phantomjs

I am trying to do some Google Analytics testing on my site which is image heavy, so I want to  disable the images. But if I set

```
service_args = ['--load-images=False']
```

the Google Analytics does not register the visit as the analytics requires a singel pixel gif call.

According to google:

> When all this information is collected, it is sent to the Analytics servers in the form of a long list of parameters attached to a single-pixel GIF image request. The data contained in the GIF request is the data sent to the Google Analytics servers, which then gets processed and ends up in your reports. Here is an example of only a portion of a GIF request:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4&utmn=769876874&utmhn=example.com&utmcs=ISO-8859-1&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=9.0%20%20r115&utmcn=1&utmdt=GATC012%20setting%20variables&utmhid=2059107202&utmr=0&utmp=/auto/GATC012.html?utm_source=www.gatc012.org&utm_campaign=campaign+gatc012&utm_term=keywords+gatc012&utm_content=content+gatc012&utm_medium=medium+gatc012&utmac=UA-30138-1&utmcc=__utma%3D97315849.1774621898.1207701397.1207701397.1207701397.1%3B...
```

How can I selectively disable all images except the Google Analytics' one?

Comment: Any workaround suggested would be fine. Anyone??

Comment: i think the only available solution is to change original code of phantomjs